# Manipulate doesn't work correctly

Tags: manipulate, image3d

Suddenly, Manipulate has stopped working in a Notebook that until recently worked perfectly.
I want to animate a plot of rotations of a cube.
I define the rotation matrices

```
Rz[\[Phi]_] = {{Cos[\[Phi]], -Sin[\[Phi]], 0}, {Sin[\[Phi]], 
Cos[\[Phi]], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}; 
Ry[\[Phi]_] = {{Cos[\[Phi]], 0, Sin[\[Phi]]}, {0, 1, 
0}, {-Sin[\[Phi]], 0, Cos[\[Phi]]}}; 
Rx[\[Phi]_] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[\[Phi]], -Sin[\[Phi]]}, {0, 
Sin[\[Phi]], Cos[\[Phi]]}};
```

then some definitions of objects

```
LetraX = {{1, -.3, -.7}, {1, .7, .7}, {1,.2,0}, {1, -.3, .7}, {1,.7,-.7}};
LetraY = {{1, .2, -.7}, {1, .2,0}, {1, -.3, .7}, {1, .2,0}, {1, .7, .7}};
LetraZ = {{1, .7, -.7}, {1, -.3, -.7}, {1, .7,.7}, {1, -.3, .7}};
Signom = {{1, -.7, 0}, {1, -.3, 0}};
SignoM = {{1, -.7, 0}, {1, -.3, 0}, {1, -.5, 0}, {1, -.5, .2}, {1, -.5, -.2}};
```

and then this is a frame of the plot that I want to manipulate

```
t = 1; s = 0; 
Show[
Graphics3D[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[2],Arrow[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0,0}}]}],
Graphics3D[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[2],Arrow[{{0, -2, 0}, {0,2,0}}]}],
Graphics3D[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[2],Arrow[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0,2}}]}],
Graphics3D[{White,Polygon[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2], #] & /@ {{1, -1, -1}, {1, -1,       1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}}]}],
Graphics3D[{White,Polygon[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2], #] & /@ {{-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1,1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}}]}],
Graphics3D[{White,Polygon[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2], #] & /@ {{-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1,1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]}],
Graphics3D[{White,Polygon[Dot[-Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2], #] & /@ {{1, -1, -1}, {1,-1,1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}}]}],
Graphics3D[{White,Polygon[Dot[-Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2], #] & /@ {{-1, 1, -1}, {-1,1,1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}}]}],
Graphics3D[{White,Polygon[Dot[-Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2], #] & /@ {{-1, -1, 1}, {1,-1,1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2], #] & /@ LetraX]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2], #] & /@ SignoM]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Rz[Pi/2], #] & /@ LetraY]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Rz[Pi/2], #] & /@ SignoM]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Ry[-Pi/2], #] & /@ SignoM]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Ry[-Pi/2], #] & /@ LetraZ]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Ry[Pi], #] & /@ LetraX]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Ry[Pi], #] & /@ Signom]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Rz[Pi], #] & /@ (Dot[Rz[Pi/2], #] & /@LetraY)]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Rz[Pi], #] & /@ (Dot[Rz[Pi/2], #] & /@Signom)]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Ry[Pi/2], #] & /@ Signom]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[.02], Black,Line[Dot[Ry[Pi s/2] . Rx[Pi t/2] . Ry[Pi/2], #] & /@ LetraZ]}],
Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large, ViewPoint -> {50, 30, 20},Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Rotated cube]

and it works perfectly. But when I enclose that inside a Manipulate

```
Manipulate[
Show[...],{{t, 0}, -4, 4, .1}, {{s, 0}, -4, 4, .1}]
```

(inside the Show goes exactly the same as in the frame before) it shows only a blank frame. It has its control and everything, but no image.

[image: Screen capture]

If I enclose the frame in a Table and export it as a gif it works also perfectly.

And the manipulate worked perfectly some weeks ago.

What can be happening?

I have Mathematica 13.3.0 on Windows.

EDIT: I don't know the cause, but when I removed the ViewPoint -> {50, 30, 20} it worked correctly.

Comment: It works fine on 13.3.1.0 Windows 10. I will say, you should replace the many calls to Graphics3D with a single one, and list all the primitives in there. Also replace the rotation matrix stuff with `RotationMatrix` instead of listing it out manually. Make sure you have cleared the definitions of s and t before using the manipulate too, and check that dynamics is enabled.

Comment: Have you deleted the definition of t and s inside your code?

Comment: Thanks, @flinty. Yes t, and s are not initialized inside the Manipulate.  Manipulate works correctly in other parts of the notebook, so the configuration is correct. I use separate Graphics3D because in this way I find it more readable and easier to copy and paste between different instructions. I'll try to simplify it, though.

Comment: It is working, if you delete the sequance of  Options for Show.  You don't need show, just put all arguments of Graphics3D in a single list as an argument to Graphics3D

Comment: Works fine as is on 13.3.0 Windows 10